# ¿Cómo poner un borde a una ventana modal en ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

No sé cómo poner un borde de color a una ventana modal en un proyecto en ReactJS.

```
<Dialog visible={asistenciaDialog}
 style={{ width: '1100px', height: '400px' }}
 modal className='p-fluid' onHide={hideDialog}>
```

Comment: agrega en el style -> `border: '1px solid black'`

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tienes varias opciones:

En primer lugar, usando css directamente puedes usar la propiedad `border: 1px solid blue` dandole en el primer parametro el grosor del borde, en el segundo el tipo de linea que quieres que tenga y en el tercero el color. Te dejo por aqui un link a la documentacion de w3schools para que veas todas las propiedades que tienes: [W3SCHOOLS BORDER](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Por otra parte, puedes usar bootstrap, teniendo sus bordes predefinidos y un poco mas actualizados a los diseños de hoy en dia. Para usarlo, primero tendras que incluirlo en tu proyecto [Como incluir bootstrap 5 en tu proyecto](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/download/) y despues aplicarle al nombre de la clase el nombre `border` dejandolo asi: `class= "border"`. Te dejo por aqui tambien la documentacion de bootstrap para los bordes para que le heches un vistazo: [Bordes en bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/borders/#border)

Un saludo, espero haberte ayudado!